# Did Harry Mulisch plagiarise other works in his novel The Assault / De aanslag?

Tags: dutch-language, plagiarism, harry-mulisch, the-assault

In 1986, Harry Mulisch's 1982 novel [*De aanslag* / *The Assault*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Assault) was turned in to [a film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Assault_(film)) directed by Fons Rademakers. Screenwriter [Gerard Soeteman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerard_Soeteman) said about the novel:

> Ik heb het boek dan ook alleen bewerkt tot scenario omdat Rademakers dat aan mij vroeg en ik nog bij hem in het krijt stond. *De Aanslag* is van alle kanten bij elkaar gejat: van ‘De perzik der onsterfelijkheid’ van Wolkers tot Het Meisje met het rode Haar, van Rashomon van Akira Kurosawa tot ‘Het behouden huis’ van W.F. Hermans.”

(Source: [Neerlands Filmdoek](http://www.nlfilmdoek.nl/artikelen/special/de-drie-nederlandse-oscarwinnende-films/).)

English translation:

> I adapted the book into a screenplay only because Rademakers asked me and because I still owed him. *The Assault* is full of stolen materials/ideas: from *The peach of immortality* by [Wolkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Wolkers) to *The Girl with the Red Hair* by [Theun de Vries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theun_de_Vries), from *Rashomon* by Akira Kurosawa to *Het behouden huis* by [W. F. Hermans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willem_Frederik_Hermans).

If this statement is true, what exactly did Harry Mulisch "steal" from the works that Soeteman mentions?

Comment: I'm wondering (having no command of Dutch whatsoever) if Soeteman is talking about the film or the novel. In particular, _Rashomon_ is a film, so it'd make more sense for a film to borrow/plagiarise some elements from it... but then it could be just my pinhole.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I also added and translated the preceding sentence from the interview. Due to that sentence, I think he is talking about the book, even though *Rashomon* is a film. (And why couldn't films provide ideas for novels?)

Comment: No reason at all, it's just that I was under the impression that it mostly happens the other way around (might be just the recent influx of film adaptations, hence the "pinhole").

Comment: My mother tongue is Dutch. The English translation is correct in that Soeteman states he 'changed/worked'  the book into a movie.

Comment: @Mirte Thanks. Dutch is also my native language and I read *De aanslag* at school (quite some time ago now).